# Java class calls method which uses hibernate - It errors when it is run multiple times

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions

I have a web app with a servlet that calls a java method to perform an insert on my database using hibernate.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); //This line triggers the exception
session.beginTransaction();
.
.
.
session.save(purchase);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
sessionFactory.close();
```

The first time I submit the form on the web page, all the information goes through and into the database, If I do it again without restarting tomcat, then I get this exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [GasPurchaseServlet] in context with path [/CarDB] threw exception
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess(AbstractSessionImpl.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:999)
    at [packageName].Main.[methodName](Main.java:95)
    at [packageName].[ServletName].doPost([ServletName].java:83)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems like I must be doing something wrong with the session or sessionFactory or transaction with not closing properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sessionfactory should not be closed after use. [as per hibernate doc of SessionFactory:](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html)

> The main contract here is the creation of Session instances. Usually an application has a single SessionFactory instance and threads servicing client requests obtain Session instances from this factory.